# Windows Wont Boot After Power Outage?

Tags: windows-xp, crash, reboot, service-pack

I have a computer that I was installing Service Pack 3 on, and then someone drove into a power pole and took out my power. Now my computer will not boot into Windows, it goes to the loading screen with the blue bar and just restarts. Any ideas on how to either finish the install or uninstall and get it to boot into Windows?

It will not boot into safe-mode either.

Comment: maybe
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a XP with SP2 install disc, do a "repair" of XP, then install SP3, then do Windows updates until there are no more available.

You may have to reinstall motherboard drivers when done repairing.

http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/How-to-repair-Windows-XP-t138.html

.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fail-safe mode? You should be able to enter it by pressing F8 before the Windows loading screen appears upon booting.

Comment: Fail-safe mode?

Comment: Safe Mode doesn't work. Tried it.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can boot into Safe Mode (Pressing F8 on startup).  If you can you may be able to roll back the service pack and reinstall it.

Comment: No it can not boot into safe mode.